# C# - Reading a file to a list and splitting on a delimiter

Tags: c#, .net, text-parsing

I have a text file that I need to pull individual values from. An example of this is:

```
Name: John Doe
Key Length: 3
a90nm84ang9834n
90v84jgseidfrlg
f39048s9ipu4sdd
Random: true
```

And I would need my output to be something like:

```
Visitor: John Doe
Key Value: a90nm84ang9834n90v84jgseidfrlgf39048s9ipu4sdd
```

Right now, I am reading the file into a list and calling on the values individually, but this doesn't allow me to rename the first value of the string (e.g. Name -> Visitor).

My real question is after the file is read into the list, is it possible to further split each of those lines off of a delimiter and reference 1 portion of the pair?

Edit - Here's a sample of the code I'm using, but it doesn't do what I am trying to do:

```
string path = @"C:\temp\foo.txt";
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + path);
Console.WriteLine("Length: " + lines[1]); //This outputs "Length: Key Length: 3"
```

Comment: Question is not very clear. It would be usefult to see what is your current code

Comment: Please post what you've tried in your question.  How are multiple entries separated in your text file? Newlines?

Comment: If you're not stuck with using `C#`, the [PowerShell Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/) just posted [a very useful article series](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2019/01/18/parsing-text-with-powershell-1-3/) on text parsing.  Prior `powershell` knowledge is not necessary.

Comment: Hint: [File.ReadAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2) "reads all lines of the file into a string array". You can use string.Split with `':'` to split at colons.

Comment: Your list entry is name + " " + key all together as one string?

Comment: Just added a code snippet. I am locked into using C# as this is part of a larger project.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm not sure what you mean by multiple entries. In the example that I originally posted, you can see that it is mixed. Most are line-separated and on each line is a pair delimited with a colon. There is an exception where one line defines how many lines the key value is split into, but that is a different problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is all formatted the same...how about something like this:

```
private static void ParseDataFile(string dataFile)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains("Name"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Visitor: {lines[i].Remove(0, 6)}");
            var keyLineCount = Convert.ToInt32(lines[++i].Remove(0, 12));
            string key = string.Empty;

            for (var j = 0; j < keyLineCount; j++)
            {
                key += lines[++i];
            }

            i++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Key Value: {key}");
        }
    }
}
```

To answer your specific question: Yes, it is possible to split strings on various characters at different times:

```
string s = "1234567890";
string[] parts1 = s.Split('5'); // 2 parts "1234" and "67890"
string[] parts2 = parts1[1].Split('7','9'); // 3 parts "6", "8" and "0"
```

etc.